# Permission denied error creating a product set in google cloud vision product search

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I am trying to create a product set on Google Cloud Vision Product Search, but I am getting a Permission denied error.

The Cloud Vision API is enabled in my project and the the service account key has Owner role. So, I do not know what is going on here.

Request:
curl -X POST      -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)"      -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"      --data @./request.json   "https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/projects/$PROJECT/locations/$LOCATION/productSets"

Error:

{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission denied.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"

Would you mind helping me on this?

Thanks
Eric

Answer (score 0):

I already fixed this. My problem was the project ID. I was using an incorrect one.